# how do i implement a google doc-like app on mobile?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, node.js, operational-transform

I'm currently working on a project similar to google docs. Basically, it allows
multiple users to edit word documents concurently in a web browser. I've been 
working extensively in pure javascript nodejs and socket.io. The web based
text editor was written from scratch using HTML5, CSS and Javascript. I handled
Operational Transformation(OT) with shareJS(server & client library that allows 
realtime editing).

The challenge I'm having now is with mobile development, where I typically want 
to develop for both android and iOS. I've been unsure about the right workflow and
technical decisions to make. Below is what has been going through my mind:

How do I incorporate my javascript application into a native iOS/Android app? Should
I just build an exact clone of what I have on the web from scratch? I mean build a 
replica of my web implementation in iOS(Swift)/Android(Java). Of course this would mean
re-writing my text editor and OT scripts from scratch in the native language. Does that 
make sense?

I know of NativeScript and phonegap. But then, when it comes to mobile, I prefer leaning
towards the native language. Is there a way to wrap my javascript into Swift/Android in 
order to call my javascript functions?

Have been thinkin about this for weeks now, pondering over how to go about this. I think i need suggestions,
thoughts and advice from other frames of reference. Thanks in advance

Comment: For iOS native development, if you need to load JavaScript and CSS, there is only one way - `UIWebView`. **BUT** If your application only contains webview then Apple will reject your application.

Comment: @kampai Thank you for the response. This feels like a glimmer of hope already. But then, can web view load the javascript and css from an external resource? say from an external url?

Comment: Yes it can load resources from external URL too.